# How to override jasmine.Spec.prototype.addExpectationResult for Protractor in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor

I have some (actually a lot) of Protractor tests in **TypeScript** and I need to take a screenshot in case of failures - from an `expect`or timeout - and I want to use the image on my [Allure Report](http://allure.qatools.ru/).

I originally tried the solution presented at [Protractor's FAQ](https://www.protractortest.org/#/faq#how-can-i-get-screenshots-of-failures-) creating a custom report or taking the screenshot inside the `jasmine. getEnv().afterAll` but that didn't work - the image is being attached to the wrong spec.

So I tried to overriding `jasmine.Spec.prototype.addExpectationResult`, but I'm getting the error: **"Property 'Spec' does not exist on type 'typeof jasmine'.ts(2339)"**.

I used a workaround to make that work (and it actually worked) as you can see bellow:

```js
const jasmine2 = jasmine as any; // <--- HERE !!!
const addExpectationResult = jasmine2.Spec.prototype.addExpectationResult;

jasmine2.Spec.prototype.addExpectationResult = function() {
  if (!arguments[0]) {
    // Takes screenshot
    allure.createAttachment('screenshot', Buffer.from(base64, 'base64'), 'image/png');
  }

  return addExpectationResult.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

BUT is there any way of overrinding the `addExpectationResult` in a "better" way in **TypeScript**?

I have in my `package.json` file the following `@types`:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/jasmine": "^3.4.4",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8"
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there definitely no way to achieve this using the allure reporter alone? Can you check out [this thread](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-jasmine/issues/1#issuecomment-137540812)

Comment: Yeah I forgot to mention. This works but it takes a screenshot for every spec. I need to take a screenshot only when the spec fails.